# Calculating weekly Hires, Rehires, and Terminations from monthly snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a table that contains a snapshot of every employees data at the end of each month until the month they leave the company. This table also has the snapshot of each employee for the current day which is replaced each day until the end of the month.

What we're trying to do is select weekly statistics for Hires, Rehires, and Terms for each department. However since we only capture data by month and not by week, I'm having trouble breaking this down by week without getting duplicates.

I'm able to pull monthly statistics similar to this. Is there a method to group by each week in a month if there is only an entry for a month?

```
select 
    Max(AsOfDate) as AsOfDate,
    Sector,
    Department,

    sum(case
        when DatePart(Year, TermDate) = DatePart(Year, AsOfDate) and DatePart(Month, TermDate) = DatePart(Month, AsOfDate) then 1
        else 0
    end) as Terms,

    sum(case
        when DatePart(Year, HireDate) = DatePart(Year, AsOfDate) and DatePart(Month, HireDate) = DatePart(Month, AsOfDate) then 1
        else 0
    end) as Hires,

    sum(case
        when DatePart(Year, RehireDate) = DatePart(Year, AsOfDate) and DatePart(Month, RehireDate) = DatePart(Month, AsOfDate) then 1
        else 0
    end) as Rehires

from Employee_History
group by Year(AsOfDate), datepart(Month, AsOfDate), Department
```

Example data if today was 2022-03-17

| AsOfDate | EmployeeID | Department | Title | HireDate | RehireDate | TermDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | EMP22 | HR | Admin | 2021-01-12 | null | 2022-01-17 |
| 2022-01-31 | EMP45 | IT | Programmer | 2022-01-10 | null | null |
| 2022-02-28 | EMP45 | IT | Programmer | 2022-01-10 | null | null |
| 2022-03-17 | EMP45 | IT | Programmer | 2022-01-10 | null | null |
| 2022-01-31 | EMP03 | IT | Manager | 2018-08-17 | 2022-01-24 | null |
| 2022-02-28 | EMP03 | IT | Manager | 2018-08-17 | 2022-01-24 | null |
| 2022-03-17 | EMP03 | IT | Manager | 2018-08-17 | 2022-01-24 | null |

Desired output for January 2022 for example

| AsOfDate | Department | Hires | Rehires | Terms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | HR | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-08 | HR | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-15 | HR | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-22 | HR | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-29 | HR | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | IT | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-08 | IT | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-15 | IT | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-22 | IT | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-29 | IT | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Sample data and desired output for the sample data would go a long way to making this clear.

Comment: I added output but the question was closed for some reason.

Comment: Where the last three days of January go? The as of date is 1/31 but the last date in the results is 1/28. Does it only go until the last Friday of the month?

Comment: Sorry about that, It was supposed to be with weeks ending on Saturdays and the numbers rolling up by week (I've adjusted the dates). Jan 30th and 31st would roll up to the end of the next week being Feb 5th

Comment: Where do you get 1 Term for AsOfDate = 2022-01-22?  Your input data doesn't have anything before 2021-01-31.  Please provide better sample inputs.

Comment: @dougp That is the problem we're trying to solve. We only have a snapshot at the end of each month and the "current date" before the month ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a mapping table for week <-> end of the Month thing containing:

```sql
create table weekmap(asOfDate DATE PRIMARY KEY, weekDayStart DATE, weekDayEnd DATE)
```

One problem is that your snapshot table contains "current date" if month isn't finished. I would advice to change that so it always has end of month to simplify stuff. Alternatively, create new column for that.

Populate it with whatever logic your weeks should be, some use ISO WEEK, some use day from start of new year etc.

Then you join your snapshot against this table (and you need to handle case where asOfDate isn't end of the month):

```sql
select w.asOfDate, w.weekDayStart, t.Department
, SUM(case when HireDate between weekdaystart and weekdayend then 1 else 0 end) AS hires
, SUM(case when ReHireDate between weekdaystart and weekdayend then 1 else 0 end) AS rehires
, SUM(case when TermDate between weekdaystart and weekdayend then 1 else 0 end) AS term
from snapshottable t
inner join weekmap w
 ON w.asOfDate = t.asOfDateFixedEndOfMonth
group by w.asOfDate, w.weekDayStart, t.Department
```

There will be some loss of data if a guy is hired and fired twice in one month, but then you probably have a bigger problem

Comment: Probably a decent idea to do it this way. I was trying to use window functions in my other attempts but I'm not great at those. I'll give this a shot and follow up.